# Nesting listings in an environment

Tags: listings, environments

I'm trying to define an outer environment around `lstlisting` (using `quotation` as an example). I tried:

```latex
\newenvironment{quotelst}{%
\begin{quotation}
\begin{lstlisting}[]
}{%
\end{lstlisting}
\end{quotation}
}
```

and

```latex
\lstnewenvironment{lstquote}{%
\begin{quotation}
}{%
\end{quotation}
}
```

Neither works (`no legal \end found`), even though this works fine:

```latex
\begin{quotation}
  \begin{lstlisting}
    some code
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{quotation}
```

I suspect `Verbatim` has something to do with it, but I couldn't find an answer on the forum (though there are many related questions). Is this doable?

Answer (score 1):

If you want that the environment has wider margins, you can use `listings` features. You *can* also do it with `quotation`, but I don't see any advantage. Anyway, the trick is to use the “command form”, `\quotation` and `\endquotation`.

You can note that the spacing with `quotation` is very wide, because LaTeX adds the spacing proper to `quotation` to the spacing of `lstlisting`.

In both cases I define an optional argument for options to the underlying `lstlisting` environment. I use it for adding a box that shows the actual margins.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=fullflexible,breaklines}

\lstnewenvironment{lstquote}[1][]
 {\lstset{#1}\quotation}
 {\endquotation}

\lstnewenvironment{lstnarrow}[1][]
 {\lstset{xleftmargin=\leftmargini,xrightmargin=\leftmargini,#1}}
 {}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-5]

\begin{lstquote}[escapeinside=@@]
aaaaaaa bbbbbbbb ccccccccc dddddddddddd eeeeeeeeee fffff
@\makebox[\linewidth][s]{x\hfil x}@
\end{lstquote}

\lipsum[2][1-5]

\begin{lstnarrow}[escapeinside=@@]
aaaaaaa bbbbbbbb ccccccccc dddddddddddd eeeeeeeeee fffff
@\makebox[\linewidth][s]{x\hfil x}@
\end{lstnarrow}

\lipsum[3][1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had tried using `\lstlisting` and `\endlstlisting`, bot not the other way around. The problem is that `quotation` was only an example. My ultimate goal is to nest inside `tcolorbox`, and `\tcolorbox`/`\endtcolorbox` doesn't work. I know I can use `tcolorbox`'s own support for `listings`, but I run into problems there too.

Comment: @MichelCharpentier I'm not sure what problems you run into, but support of `listings` in `tcolorbox` is quite good. Perhaps it's better to open a new question with the actual problem.

Comment: I did, and I've already received an answer.  Unfortunately, not something that solves the problem.  The question is "gobble option of listing when used via tcolorbox" (I don't know how to link to another question in this forum).